# PCA dimensions question

Tags: linear-algebra, principal-component-analysis

I read this quote in some lectures about PCA:

" Also, since n points in a p-dimensional space defines
a linear subspace whose dimension is at most n−1, we would find that p−n+ 1
eigenvalues are zero."*

For context, this is about the eigendecomposition of the sample covariance matrix $S = \frac{X^T X}{n-1}$ where $X$ is an n x p matrix with n less than p. The quote seems to say that p - n + 1 of its eigenvalues will be zero, but I thought that p - n of its eigenvalues would be zero (because the number of non-zero eigenvalues of S is equal to the rank of S, which is less than or equal to n?

I am confused because I thought that n points in a p-dimensional space define a linear subspace whose dimension is at most n.

Can anybody point out the mistake?

---

*This quote is from page 40 of https://courses.maths.ox.ac.uk/node/view_material/37962

Comment: In the context, they are talking about [affine subspaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space). It is indeed true that $n$ points (generally) determine a dimension $n$  (vector) subspace

Comment: Note that because the columns of the matrix $X$ have mean zero, $X$ has a non-trivial nullspace and the rank of $X$ will be at most $n-1$.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - very helpful :)